# How to make bold letters in the answer choices?

Tags: bold, exam

How can I make all the 4 letters that indicate answer choices bold?

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,A4paper,final,leqno]{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\renewcommand\questionlabel{\thequestion.} %replace period with parenthesis
\renewcommand{\thequestion}{\bfseries\large\arabic{question}}

%\printanswers

\begin{document}


\begin{questions}

\question A straight line $2x-y=8$ meets another one at ...


\begin{choices}
\choice  $(-1;2)$
\choice $(5;3)$
\choice $(2;4)$
\choice $(5;2)$
\end{choices}
\begin{solution} $(D)$. 
\end{solution}




\question Circle $x^2+y^2=1$  meets ...

\begin{choices}
\choice  $(-1;2)$
\choice $(5;3)$
\choice $(2;4)$
\choice $(5;2)$
\end{choices}
\begin{solution} $(D)$. 
\end{solution}

\end{questions}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try providing the instruction `\renewcommand{\thechoice}{\bfseries\large\Alph{choice}}`?

Comment: Glad it works for you. I'll post my comment as an answer, so that the query can be treated as having received an "official answer".

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you add the instruction

```
\renewcommand{\thechoice}{\bfseries\large\Alph{choice}}
```

to the preamble.

Aside: One of the document class options should be spelled as `a4paper`, not `A4paper`.

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper,final,leqno]{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath}

%%\renewcommand\questionlabel{\thequestion.} %replace period with parenthesis
\renewcommand{\thequestion}{\bfseries\large\arabic{question}}

\renewcommand{\thechoice}{\bfseries\large\Alph{choice}} % <-- new

%\printanswers

\begin{document}


\begin{questions}

\question A straight line $2x-y=8$ meets another one at \dots

\begin{choices}
\choice  $(-1;2)$
\choice $(5;3)$
\choice $(2;4)$
\choice $(5;2)$
\end{choices}
\begin{solution} $(D)$.
\end{solution}

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Formatting instructions should not be part of `\thequestion` or `\thechoice`, but rather they belong in `\questionlabel` and `\choicelabel`.

I'd avoid `\large`, as boldface is by itself giving enough prominence.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,a4paper,final,leqno]{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\renewcommand\questionlabel{\bfseries\thequestion.} %replace period with parenthesis
\renewcommand{\thequestion}{\arabic{question}}
\renewcommand{\choicelabel}{\bfseries\thechoice.}

%\printanswers

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question A straight line $2x-y=8$ meets another one at ...

\begin{choices}
\choice $(-1;2)$
\choice $(5;3)$
\choice $(2;4)$
\choice $(5;2)$
\end{choices}
\begin{solution}
(D).
\end{solution}




\question Circle $x^2+y^2=1$  meets ...

\begin{choices}
\choice $(-1;2)$
\choice $(5;3)$
\choice $(2;4)$
\choice $(5;2)$
\end{choices}
\begin{solution}
(D).
\end{solution}

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you explain the reason for "Formatting instructions should not be part of \thequestion or \thechoice, but rather they belong in \questionlabel and \choicelabel.".

Comment: @pzorba75 You'd get the same formatting instructions with `\ref`, which doesn't seem to be wanted. Possibly it's not an issue with `exam`, it would be with other documents.